# Using the CAML <Or> and <And> Operators

Tags: logical-operators, caml, sharepoint-list, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to write a CAML query that does the following:

Get all rows where the _ModerationStatus is Approved.

Get all rows where the _ModerationStatus is Rejected and the row's Requester is the current user, or the row's Manager is the current user.

Get all rows where the _ModerationStatus is Pending and the row's Requester is the current user, or the row's Manager is the current user.

So far I have this CAML query, but when I run it, I get the error `Cannot complete this action. Please try again.`

```
<View>
<Query>
    <Where>
        <Or>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='_ModerationStatus' />
                <Value Type='ModStat'>Approved</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Or>
                <And>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='_ModerationStatus' />
                        <Value Type='ModStat'>Pending</Value>
                    </Eq>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='Requester' />
                        <Value Type='Integer'><UserID /></Value>
                    </Eq>
                </And>
                <And>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='_ModerationStatus' />
                        <Value Type='ModStat'>Pending</Value>
                    </Eq>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='Manager' />
                        <Value Type='Integer'><UserID /></Value>
                    </Eq>
                </And>
            </Or>
            <Or>
                <And>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='_ModerationStatus' />
                        <Value Type='ModStat'>Rejected</Value>
                    </Eq>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='Requester' />
                        <Value Type='Integer'><UserID /></Value>
                    </Eq>
                </And>
                <And>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='_ModerationStatus' />
                        <Value Type='ModStat'>Rejected</Value>
                    </Eq>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='Manager' />
                        <Value Type='Integer'><UserID /></Value>
                    </Eq>
                </And>
            </Or>
        </Or>
    </Where>
</Query>
</View>
```

I'm pretty sure that I'm not applying the `<Or>` and `<And>` operators correctly, because simpler queries like these three do work for me:

```
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='_ModerationStatus' />
                <Value Type='ModStat'>Approved</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>

<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='_ModerationStatus' />
                <Value Type='ModStat'>Rejected</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>

<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='_ModerationStatus' />
                <Value Type='ModStat'>Pending</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up with this valid Caml using the [U2U Caml Query Builder](http://www.u2u.be/Software).

```
<Query>
<Where>
  <Or>
     <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='_ModerationStatus' />
        <Value Type='ModStat'>Approved</Value>
     </Eq>
     <Or>
        <And>
           <Eq>
              <FieldRef Name='_ModerationStatus' />
              <Value Type='ModStat'>Rejected</Value>
           </Eq>
           <Or>
              <Eq>
                 <FieldRef Name='Requester' />
                 <Value Type='User'>
                    <UserID />
                 </Value>
              </Eq>
              <Eq>
                 <FieldRef Name='Manager' />
                 <Value Type='User'>
                    <UserID />
                 </Value>
              </Eq>
           </Or>
        </And>
        <And>
           <Eq>
              <FieldRef Name='_ModerationStatus' />
              <Value Type='ModStat'>Pending</Value>
           </Eq>
           <Or>
              <Eq>
                 <FieldRef Name='Requester' />
                 <Value Type='User'>
                    <UserID />
                 </Value>
              </Eq>
              <Eq>
                 <FieldRef Name='Manager' />
                 <Value Type='User'>
                    <UserID />
                 </Value>
              </Eq>
           </Or>
        </And>
     </Or>
  </Or>
</Where>
<OrderBy>
  <FieldRef Name='EventDate' Ascending='True' />
</OrderBy>
</Query>
<ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name='Title' />
    <FieldRef Name='Location' />
    <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
    <FieldRef Name='EndDate' />
    <FieldRef Name='Description' />
    <FieldRef Name='Requester' />
    <FieldRef Name='Manager' />
</ViewFields>
<QueryOptions />
```